# ViewModel in post action is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Can someone help me to know why `model.Prod`is null like in the picture below and `model.catg` is not null? There are items in my Product table. And also after i add `@Html.HiddenFor(p=>p.Prod[i].id)` to the view, `model.Prod` is not null but only `id` has value. Other parameters are still null.

[image]

```
@model HandMShop.ViewModel.HMViewM

@using (Html.BeginForm("ShopPage", "Shop", FormMethod.Post)) {

@for(int i=0;i< Model.catg.Count;i++)  {
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.catg[i].IsChecked)
<label>@Model.catg[i].CategoryName</label>
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.catg[i].id)
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.catg[i].CategoryName }

 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Prod.Count; i++) {
 <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
 <figure class="card card-product mehsul">
 <div class="img-wrap"> <img class="img-fluid mehsulimg" 
 src="@Model.Prod[i].PhotoProducts.First().ImageName" alt=""> </div>
 <div class="handhover">
 <img class="img-fluid" src="@Model.Prod[i].PhotoProducts.Last().ImageName" alt=""> 
 </div>
 <figcaption class="info-wrap">
 <h4 class="title">@Model.Prod[i].ProdName</h4>
 <p class="desc">@Model.Prod[i].Description</p>
 </figcaption>
 </figure>
  </div> 
      }
```

View Model I used:

```
public class HMViewM
{
    public List<User> userr { get; set; }
    public List<homesec1slider> homesec1 { get; set; }
    public List<Category>  catg { get;set; }
    public List<Colour> colrs { get; set; }
    public List<PhotoProduct> Photopr { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Prod { get; set; }
    public bool Istehsal { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShopPage(HMViewM model)
    {
        List<Category> selectedcatg = model.catg.Where(x => x.IsChecked == true).ToList();
        List<Product> selectedprod = model.Prod.Where(i => i.CategoryId == selectedcatg.FirstOrDefault().id).ToList();
        var vm = new HMViewM
        {
            Prod = selectedprod,
            catg = _context.Categories.ToList(),
            colrs = _context.Colours.ToList(),
            Photopr = _context.PhotoProducts.Where(ph => ph.Product.id == ph.ImageId).ToList(),
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because after page being postbacked by clicking submit button, only those properties will be return to your controller that you explicitly bind them to html `input` elements.
Values that binded in your code is:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.catg[i].IsChecked)

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.catg[i].id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.catg[i].CategoryName }
```

So only these values filled in your controller `HMViewM` object.
If you want other values you should bind them to html input elements too (using hidden field, text, checkbox ...)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have many properties. Should I write all of them manually or is there any other way?

Comment: @Aytac: No other way. In general it's not a good idea to bind properties that you don't want to change them in `view` because it has negative impact on request time of page, instead it's better to only bind their Id and fetch their other props server side

Comment: I understand. Thank you.